# RepositoryEventHandler and handle before GET

Tags: spring-data-rest

the `RepositoryEntityController` sends events on `DELETE`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, `POST`, but **not** on `GET` requests. As a result one can create `@HandleBeforeSave`, `@HandleBeforeCreate` and `@HandleBeforeDelete` methods, but not `@HandleBeforeGet` method.

Is there any particular reason for this to be?

I'd like to integrate Spring Security ACL and Spring Data REST. However I don't want to override all the methods from `CrudRpository` and `JpaRepository` and to annotate them with `@PreAuthorize`. Instead I want to write a `@RepositoryEventHandler` and check if the current user has permissions and if not then throw `AccessDeniedException`. However to do that I need to have `HandleBeforeGet` event

Comment: You should use Spring Security to [authorize](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#authorize-requests) GET requests for authenticated users only.

Comment: You might also try using the [ResourceProcessorInterface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_resourceprocessor_interface) and throw some Exception when the user is not authorized. But as Marc suggested, using Spring security for this seems like cleaner approach.